# Cointegration and long run restrictions

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

Below is a typical output from a 5 variable VECM model with 4 cointegrating vectors with $r-1$ restrictions on each equation. Therefore, the top part of the output is a diagonal matrix by default. For instance, $ect1$  is $x_1=-0.5574268x_4+21.07965$ and $ect2$ is $x_2=-0.4633047x_4+4.424252$ etc as seen in the output. Let's now say the theory suggests I should model $x_1$ as $$x_1=\beta_1x_2+\beta_2x_3-\beta_3x_4-\beta_4x_5$$ Let's also say I want to give economic meaning to the $\beta's$ as long-run 'elasticities' as the $x's$ are in log form.
How will I be able to obtain this equation while accounting for other CVs i.e. $ect2$, $ect3$ and $ect4$.

```
               ect1          ect2          ect3      ect4
   X1      1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.00000000  0.000000e+00
   X2      0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  0.00000000  0.000000e+00
   X3      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  1.00000000  0.000000e+00
   X4      0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.00000000  1.000000e+00
   X5      5.574268e-01 -4.633047e-01  0.25466051  2.523022e-02
constant  -2.107965e+01 -4.424252e+00 -4.92108590 -2.599895e+00
```

Can you please advise what sort of restrictions matrix I should create? I guess, I will do overidentifying restrictions for this, but any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You start with *I have another cointegration related question.* To make this meaningful, you could add links to your other question(s) (if they are relevant to this one). Otherwise you may just delete the sentence.

Comment: @RichardHardy, just changed the post.

Comment: Since you ask *How will I be able to obtain this equation while accounting for other CVs i.e. ect2, ect3 and ect4.*, does the name of structural VAR (SVAR) ring a bell? I am trying to understand what you actually are after. (I might be wasting your time since I never really worked with SVAR models, but I am just interested in your question.)

Comment: @RichardHardy, I need to run VECM as the series are co-integrated. What I need is the long run cointegrating equation, the first one of the four. The output above shows that there are four cointegrating vectors, and the normalization is default identity matrix. I need to reparameterize i.e. put some restrictions on this set of cointegrating equations so that I have the first equation with all the coefficients (as I described above). For this, I need to create a restrictions matrix, but I have failed to do it in a right way. I need help with constructing that matrix.